# every morning all the data in redis is always gone, how solved? and why?

Tags: database, redis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38F5x.png)

every morning all the data in redis is always gone, how solved? and why?

this is my redis.conf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5dqX.png)

Is this enough to keep the data from disappearing?
and please teach me why data is always disappering

Comment: is the snapshot file there? did the service get restarted?

Comment: i restarted redis service after modifying the redis.conf ( appendonly no -> appendonly yes ). and i put some data( ex, set hello world ), and i check the appendonly.aof file. i checked some command was written in that file ...(it's been good so far)  but today moring, I used the command(in the redis-cli, "KEYS *") to see if there was any data. but result was "empty list" and appendonly.aof file is existed but content was lose... what is problem?..

Comment: snapshot file(rdb) is necessary ? Isn't data persistence possible only with aof?